# Comparing array (start with option) by giving another array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two arrays;`selectedFunction` say **array1**.  with these values

```
['0x0000000000000000', '0x4046ebae00000ab003','0xd6d75f5100000cd0001']
```

and `allFunctions` say **array2**. with these values ;

```
[ '0x000fba16', '0x4046ebae', '0x517cf73e', '0xd6d75f51' ]
```

if element in array1 **starts with** the given element from array2, then push that element of array1 into `myFinalSelectedFunctions[]` say **array3**.  In above arrays, **2nd and 3rd elements of array1 should be pushed into array3**. How to perform such task in javascript/Nodejs ? I have basic knowledge of javascript, not an expert.

Comment: You can iterate through both the arrays and find the match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to return true if a hex code from array1 [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) a hex code in array2:

```js
const array1 = ['0x0000000000000000', '0x4046ebae00000ab003','0xd6d75f5100000cd0001'];
const array2 = [ '0x000fba16', '0x4046ebae', '0x517cf73e', '0xd6d75f51' ];

const res = array1.filter(hex => array2.some(code => hex.startsWith(code)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: if i want to do opposite of above requirement ... means 'if not start with' ... then how to perform such task...

Comment: @AmirAli I believe you would want to change `array2.some(code => hex.startsWith(code))` to `array2.every(code => !hex.startsWith(code))` if I understand your requirments correctly

Comment: yes, you are right and i also tried this one... it works.. thanks again... for your prompt reply...

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do following:

```js
const arr1 = ['0x0000000000000000', '0x4046ebae00000ab003','0xd6d75f5100000cd0001'];
const arr2 = [ '0x000fba16', '0x4046ebae', '0x517cf73e', '0xd6d75f51' ]

const arr3 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i].startsWith(arr2[j])) {
      arr3.push(arr1[i])
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr3)
```

Answer by @nick-parsons is much cleaner. You can go for it.